# ExtJS: Connecting a store to a combo box?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the below code, I manually add records to a store(called `dataStore`). But when I try to load the store to a combo box(labeled `cmb`), I get the following error:

> http://localhost:1841/CurrencyConvert.model.CurrencyCode?_dc=147hj_126&query=&page=1&start=0&limit=25
>   404 (Not Found)

It appears as if the store is trying to call the proxy to load data(even though it has all the data already, manually loaded by me). Following is the store:

```
Ext.define('CurrencyConvert.store.CurrencyCode', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'CurrencyConvert.model.CurrencyCode',
    storeId : 'currencyCode',
    addRate : function(currencyCode, currencyRate) {
        this.add({
            code : currencyCode,
            rate : currencyRate
        });
    }
});
```

And  Ajax request where the store is being used:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url : 'data.json',
                    method : 'GET',
                    dataType: 'currency.json',
                    item : cmb,
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        console.log('Success');
                        var result = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                        var currencyCodes = Object.keys(result.quotes);
                        this.dataStore = Ext.create('CurrencyConvert.store.CurrencyCode', {});
                        for( var x = 0; x < currencyCodes.length; x++)
                        {
                            this.dataStore.addRate(currencyCodes[x], result.quotes[currencyCodes[x]]);
                            console.log(this.dataStore.getAt(x).get('code') + " : " + this.dataStore.getAt(x).get('rate'));
                        }
                        cmb.emptyText = "-Chose Currency-";
                        cmb.store = this.dataStore;
                        console.log("Stuff: " + this.dataStore.getAt(2).get('code') + " : " + this.dataStore.getAt(2).get('rate'));         
                        cmb.displayField = 'code';
                        cmb.valueField = 'code';        


                    },
                    failure: function(response) {
                        console.log('Failed!');
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                });
```

Following is sample data I am fetching:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "timestamp":1475354167,
  "source":"USD",
  "quotes":{
    "USDAED":3.672904,
    "USDAFN":65.550003,
    "USDALL":122.239998,
    "USDAMD":473.959991,
    "USDANG":1.770403,
    "USDAOA":165.067001,
    "USDARS":15.250402,
    "USDAUD":1.304104,
    "USDAWG":1.79,
    "USDAZN":1.620604,
    "USDBAM":1.742204,
    "USDBBD":2,
    "USDBDT":78.430401,
    "USDBGN":1.752404,
    "USDBHD":0.377041,
    "USDBIF":1651,
    "USDBMD":1,
    "USDBND":1.362804,
    "USDBOB":6.860399,
    "USDZAR":13.710364,
    "USDZMK":5156.103593,
    "USDZMW":10.020363,
    "USDZWL":322.355011
  }
}
```

**EDIT: The store definition**

```
Ext.define('CurrencyConvert.model.CurrencyCode', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    pageSize: 0,
    fields : [
        {
            name : 'code',
            value : 'string'
        },
        {
            name : 'rate',
            value : 'float',

        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the store is trying to get the `model`, which you defined as

```
model : 'CurrencyConvert.model.CurrencyCode',
```

if you do so, you have to have somewhere in your codebase a definition like this:

```
Ext.define('CurrencyConvert.model.CurrencyCode',
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    ...
});
```

and you will have to have loaded that file. In 99% of the cases, the model file would be placed in `app/model/CurrencyCode.js`, the application would have the name `CurrencyConvert`, and the store would contain a `requires` section

```
requires:[
    'CurrencyConvert.model.CurrencyCode'
]
```

Comment: I added the requires but still the same message comes up. The store gets loaded correctly in my Ajax functions(the console.log's show that each of the indices have data) but somehow when I connect the store to the combo box, this error shows up. I have added my definition of the model also above. Any further suggestions would be appreciated.